How can I configure `Concurrent batches per shard` via serverless?
I am using serverless to deploy a lambda function listen on dynamodb stream updates. This is the doc: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs-providers-aws-events-streams
There is one configuration to control the lambda concurrency batches per shard as show in below screenshot. But I can't find the configuration from the doc. I only find one parallelizationFactor which is used for Kinesis. How can I configure dyanmodb stream for concurrent batches?

